# Images not loaded from js file

Tags: codeigniter

I have a javascript plugin that loads some images from the js file itself. I included the js file like that `echo '<script src="'.base_url()."js/$js_file.js".'"></script>`, the js file loaded correctly but the images not loaded. When i checked the images path from the firebug i found the path relative to the controller `http://localhost/mysite/controller/images/nicEditorIcons.gif` which the `images` is the folder that holds my images(its in the root folder).
What is the problem here? and how to let codeigniter load resources correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you should add an slash "/" before any path which is calling a resource to be relative to the root site, first locale your javascript plugin which I think there is where you add the paths to the images that I think looks like  `images/nicEditorIcons.gif` change that to look like `/images/nicEditorIcons.gif` to be relative to your root path I mean  to `http://localhost/mysite`, so that way it will look like `http://localhost/mysite/images/nickEditorIcons.gif` instead of the URL you have shown, hope it helps.